# Angular JS - Value from a service doesn't update in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working in a project with [ng-cart directive](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/). This directive has a service which includes a function `totalCost()` that updates the total amount added to a shopping cart.

In order to show it in the view, I wrote this in my controller:

```
this.totalCost = ngCart.totalCost();
```

The value shown in the view is correct, but the problem is that this value doesn't update when I add/remove items from the cart, but only when I refresh the page.

I tried with

```
$scope.$watch('ngCart.totalCost()', function() {
    this.totalCost = ngCart.totalCost();
});
```

But then `totalCost` doesn't show in the view at all.

You can check a plunkr of my code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9GzDsRWKSVgVNy0Uu3zr?p=preview)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to,

```
$scope.$watch('ngCart.totalCost()', function() {
    this.totalCost = ngCart.totalCost();
}.bind(this));
```

Because the watch callback is called by angular so, the **this** value in this function doesn't point to the controller's instance.

Here is your plunk,
http://plnkr.co/edit/HoEC0obWOPFLWbSojO7F?p=preview

I have changed the watch definition in it because ngCart.totalCost is not a property on the scope.

Comment: That was it! I was going crazy and it was in front of me, thanks for the insight.